# VB.NET How do I get the name of a BackgroundImage?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that will give the new form a BackgroundImage:

```
    Public Shared WaitForNet As Image = My.Resources.WFN
    Public Shared WaitForDB As Image = My.Resources.WFS
    Public Shared Function GetWaitFormBG(code As String) As Image
    Dim img As Image = Nothing

    Select Case code
        Case "Net"
            img = WaitForNet
        Case "DB"
            img = WaitForDB
    End Select

    Return img
End Function
```

And in the Sub I have:

```
Public Shared Sub FrmWaitLoad(ByVal R As String)
    Dim WF As New WaitForm

    WF.Tag = GetWaitFormBG(R)
    WF.Show()
End Sub
```

In WaitForm Load I have:

```
Private Sub WaitForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundImage = Tag
        If Tag = "Net" Then
        Do Until Net = True
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End If

    If Tag = "DB" Then

        T = 5

        Timer1.Interval = 60000
        Timer1.Enabled = True

        Do Until DB = True
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop

        Timer1.Stop()
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

But I get an error message:

"System.InvalidCastException: 'Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':
        Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from 'Bitmap' to 'String'.'"

If I change it from "If Tag = "Net" Then" to "If Tag = My.Resources.WFN Then" then I get "'Operator '=' is not defined for type 'Bitmap' and type 'Bitmap'.'" error

What I need is the actual name of the BackgroundImage

Thanks for the help

Comment: An image doesn't have a name, so you would have to keep track of it yourself through a variable.  Get rid of the Do-Loop Application.DoEvents.  Look up how to use the built in splash screen.

Comment: This Form is not at the beginning of the application, can I still use a splash screen?

Comment: Like just about all reference types, you need to use `Is` to compare references, i.e. whether one reference refers to the same object as another reference. You have to test whether an `Image` reference `Is WaitForNet` or `Is WaitForDB`.

Comment: You might benefit from [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks, this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

var bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myimage);
Use bitmap to send to image